# list.files taking account of list number in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a large number of files (>50,000) to analyze. I can get a list of these files with;

```
myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*output*")
```

and then loop with

```
for (file in myfiles) {
"code"
}
```

The problem is that sometimes my system freezes due to RAM overload so the only option left is to kill the rsession and restart the loop again with same files. How can I modify the list.files call, so that I can only select a certain number of files like 100:200 or 3500:5000 via list.files. Basically, I would like to skip the files which are already analyzed before the last system freeze.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'myfiles' objects is a `vector`.  So, we can create the sequence (`:`) of positions to subset the object when we loop

```
for (file in myfiles[100:200]) {
 ...code...
}
```

---

Also, the files can be `split` into a `list` with each element of length 100

```
lst1 <- split(myfiles, as.integer(gl(length(myfiles), 100, length(myfiles))))
```

Then, an idea is to loop in `parallel` or sequentially, remove (`rm`) the temporary object, call `gc()` to release memory

Comment: Let me check and I will update you. Thanks bro. I am sending you a request on LinkedIn. my profile is https://www.linkedin.com/in/sumit-gupta-9574848a/

Comment: Also better to explore packages like `data.table` or `vroom` which can speed up the analysis significantly

Comment: @akrun It is working. Actually, I use rm to remove some objects but the problem is that I am using reduce(full_join.... function to save each output in the same file. This causes memory overload. Anyway now it's better with your solution. Thanks

Comment: @gupta After the `rm`, apply the `gc()` so that the memory is released.  In some cases, if you don't call gc, the memory won't get release

Comment: @gupta Instead of `reduce(full_join`,  I would iterately join in the for loop, remove the temporary objects and assign it to the original object

Comment: @akrun Ok I will use gc() function. I missed this so far. Thanks, bro. you are helpful as always. Have a good day. :)